# Selecting certain time range in Matlab

Tags: matlab, time, fft

I have a project to do and im facing some problems. Please help me. Im not so good at matlab yet. 
Basically, I have a set of movement data (data.mat) which were recorded for 3 days non stop. And I need to:
1. select only certain certain moments (time range) of this whole set of data 
2. divide these moments into small 2.56 seconds parts
3. make FFT of each small parts , to see the movement in frequency domain, and select only 5-25 Hz 
4. find a few biggest frequency peaks

I wrote a code for making FFT and peaks for whole my data "Data.mat"  and it is working. 
This is my code:

```
load('Data.mat');
P=data1(,2); %  
Fs=100       
Ts=1/Fs        
L=length(P)     
t = (0:L-1)*Ts;    
nfft = 256    

figure(1)      % raw signal plotting
plot(t,P);

y = fft(P,nfft)/L;       % FFT
ymag = abs(y(1:length(y)/2+1));
ft = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,nfft/2+1);

figure(2)    % FFT plotting
plot(ft,2*abs(y(1:nfft/2+1)))

indx=ft>= 5 & ft<= 25; % only 5-25Hz
ftsub=ft(indx);
ymagsub=ymag(indx);

% highest peaks
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(ymagsub,'MinPeakHeight',0.02)
plot(ftsub,ymagsub,ftsub(locs),pks,'rv','MarkerFaceColor','r')
```

Now Im trying to select only certain moments of the data but I have problems with it. 
E.g. lets say, I want select only time range: 13-03-2013 9:20:00-9:45:00 AM

I have tried:

```
t_start =datenum('13-03-2013 9:20:00 AM', 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS AM');
t_end = datenum('13-03-2013 9:45:00 AM', 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS AM');
rows=find(P>= t_start & P<= t_end);
```

but I get answer:
    rows=
    Empty matrix: 0-by-1

Whats wrong? If this code is wrong, how to select certain time range then?
And how to select into 2.56 seconds ?

Please help me, Ive been trying to find the solution since weeks, im really depressed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this line to work properly:
`rows=find(P>= t_start & P<= t_end);` P must be a series of times in MATLAB `datenum` format.

I'm guessing P is your actual data - so it doesn't work because `find` simply compares the numeric values in P against the numeric date values - your "P" values aren't date-tagged in MATLAB.  The important things to remember is that the output of `datenum` is simply a number, so MATLAB will allow you to compare it against other numbers even if the result doesn't make real-world sense.

Your options are:

1. If your data contains a timestamp, load that, check that it is in the correct format (convert back with `datestr` for a sanity check). This may be the first column of your data. Perform the find on the time values and then use that to plot/extract the appropriate parts of `P`.
2. Construct a time vector - using what you know about the time of the first data point + the sampling rate, and do the same.  Similar to your `t` but in datenums. This will also work if your data acquisition means you only have the times in time-since-start-of-file plus a start time.

Then it's just something like:

```
r=find(t>= t_start & t<= t_end); 
plot(t(r),P(r);
```

Comment: In first column I have numbers of measurements: 1025600, 1025601, 1025602, 1025603 etc  so I have tried to do like:  datestr(1025600,'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS AM')
ans =30-12-2807 12:00:00 AM
>> 
datestr(1025601,'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS AM')
ans =31-12-2807 12:00:00 AM
>> 
datestr(1025602,'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS AM')
ans =01-01-2808 12:00:00 AM why its like this?

Comment: I also performed: datenum('13-03-2013 9:20:00 AM', 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS AM') and I get ans =7.3531e+05 , then I did: datenum('13-03-2013 940:00 AM', 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS AM') and I get ans =7.3531e+05. Why do I get the same number?                   Then I performed: time='13-03-2013 9:20:00 AM'; timen=datenum(time,'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS AM'); datestr(timen,'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS AM') and I got ans = 13-03-2013 9:20:00 AM

Comment: Well, I don't know what time format "1025600" is supposed to be; MATLAB `datenum` isn't automatically interchangeable with all other time formats or counters.  You will need to work out how your counts correspond to real times, and convert appropriately.  The reason you appear to get the same number with two close times is that `datenum` results increment per day, and the display is not showing you all the significant digits. If you took one output away from the other you would see a small difference.